# Age validation using 2-digit year using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to check whether the entered age is 18 years or more. I am using JavaScript to take date month and year values. Year is in 2-digit. And I want to check its age.

```
var dd = document.getElementById('age_dd').value;
var mm = document.getElementById('age_mm').value;
var yy = document.getElementById('age_yy').value; //giving 2 digit year

var dt = new Date();  //todays date
```

I can do it in simple way if I have 4-digit year, but I am confused how I can do it with 2-digit year.

Comment: `yy` is year of date of birth? What if the user was born in 1916?

Comment: yes sir.. yy giving year in 2 digit

Comment: thats the main issue. same question i also have but client have this requirement

Comment: What is client's answer to your question?

Comment: it may be 2016 or 1916 :D

Comment: in this situation we have to take 80 years back from todays year before that should be considered as wrong input

Comment: i think you should take a full date (year), and display only two digits on views.

Comment: Ask for, and store, the full year with 4 digits. Then there is no ambiguity. It also makes querying the data much simpler. You  don't know how long this data will persist or be re-used for! People have been in this mess before, assuming that their software and data created in the 1970s would be replaced by the 2000s, but sometimes it wasn't. If there's a requirement to show it using 2 digits, then do that, but that's just for displaying and does not impact on the backend data.

Comment: You can check if `00 <= yy <= 18` (where 18 is last two digits of current year) then change it to 2000...2018 otherwise 1919...1999. Of course someone who was born in 1918 will not be able to use your app.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

`date.getMonth()+1` -> 1 is added since js date returns month with index 0.

```js
var date = new Date("1994-11-19");
var isvalid = new Date(date.getFullYear()+18,date.getMonth()+1,date.getDate()) <= new Date();
console.log(isvalid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

> In this situation we have to take 80 years back from todays year
>   Before that should be considered as wrong input

You seem to assume that if the value of `yy` is greater than current year's `yy` than it is `19xx` instead of `20xx`

Convert the value to numbers

```
var dd = +document.getElementById('age_dd').value; //using unary + to convert to number
var mm = +document.getElementById('age_mm').value; //using unary + to convert to number
var yy = document.getElementById('age_yy').value; //using unary + to convert to number

var dt = new Date();  //todays date
```

get the prefix based on yy value

```
yy = Number(+yy < ( dt.getFullYear() % 100 ) ? "20" + yy : "19" + yy);
```

get date object based on entered DOB.

```
var birthDate = new Date( yy, mm - 1, dd );
```

Now finally **get the difference in years**

```
var isOlderThan18 = (dt.getFullYear() -  birthDate.getFullYear()) > 18;
```